# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditView

Tags: android, xml

I get the error in the title when i run my application, I have checked the forums but all my Edit, text views are closed. I dont really understand what the problem is, everything looks fine to me.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/fairgroundName"/>
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/rideName"/>


ride =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rideName);
fairground =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fairgroundName);
```

But I don't get what the problem is. Can anyone help please

Comment: Could you please paste the whole code when you declare and initialize your ride and fairground views?

Comment: Clean your project in eclipse, uninstall application from phone/emulator and run it again.

Comment: try cleaning the project: Project -> Clean

Comment: And I doubt you really need to cast all the way down to EditText anyway :) TextView type is mostly suitable for code manipulations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me too. Looks like the code for your EditText was not generated properly in `R.java`.

**Clean** the project. Hopefully, it would remove the error.

**Project -> Clean**

Don't forget to uninstall the application from the phone before you try running it again.

Comment: I got this same error when just swapping the positions of 2 classes inside the same linearlayout on an xml file. Swayam's advice worked for me

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you change The order of your views in layout file? Sometimes doing it cause this error. As swayam said do a Project -> Clean to regenerate your R.