# Basic calculating app crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1HpEzxYHxE)
    to create a basic calculating app.

I was able to debug it on my phone and it ran fine. However when I plug in the number and press calculate, the app freezes and crashes.

This is my layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="Basic Calculate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Calculate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Activity class:

```
package com.danielkim.danielkimcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button calc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);

        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
                TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);

                double num = Double.parseDouble(number.getText().toString());

                num = Double.parseDouble(samplecalc.multNum(num));

                display.setText(num + "");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my `samplecalc` class for doing the calculations:

```
package com.danielkim.danielkimcalculator;

public class samplecalc {
    private double Num = 0;

    public samplecalc(double number) {
        Num = number;
    }

    public static String multNum(double x) {
        String re = "";

        double num = x * 5;

        re = num + "";

        return re;
    }

    public double multNum2() {
        double re = Num * 5;

        return re;
    }
}
```

The logcat says:

```
01-24 18:56:59.760: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12532): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
01-24 18:57:29.640: W/dalvikvm(12532): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acc1f8)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.danielkim.danielkimcalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:23)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
01-24 18:57:29.650: E/AndroidRuntime(12532):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try cleaning and re-executing?

Comment: Hey it's me who made the video. Try running it again. Type in `5` and his calculate. Is the LogCat the same after that?

Comment: it's not really good to define objects inside clicklistners or other event listeners, it may be not the problem but you better correct it for better use of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are casting correct. But the compiler still complains about a faulty cast.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

I believe this is the `EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);`
I would try to clean the project **Project -> Clean** if you are using Eclipse. Faults like this may happen, and the easiest solution I have found is to just clean the project and run it again.

**Other threads concerning this issue :**

1. [android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304467/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android)
2. [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be
   cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674627/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast)
3. [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be
   cast..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215522/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-imagebutton-cannot-be-cast-to-andro)
4. [ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633482/classcastexception-android-widget-edittext)